# Как переместить обьект по вертикали?

Tags: javascript

```js
var pi = Math.PI;
var rho = 0;
var rho2 = 0.5;

function Peremeshenie() {
  document.getElementById('Ken ').style.left = rho *
    Math.cos(pi) + 'px';
  document.getElementById('Ken ').style.top = rho *
    Math.Sin(pi) + 'px';
  rho += rho2;

}
setInterval(moveByLine, 20);
```

```css
#Ken {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<div id='Ken'></div>
```

Comment: У вас id у элемента 'Ken', а находите в `document.getElementById` вы почему-то 'Ken '. Чтобы перемещать объект по странице свойствами `left` и `top`, нужно выдать ему абсолютное позиционирование (`position: absolute`). Не `Math.Sin`, а `Math.sin`. В `setInterval()` не `moveByLine` (откуда это название вообще взято), а, вероятно, `Peremeshenie`. Сам интервал очень маленький - выставьте хотя бы 200. Манипуляции с косинусами/синусами, конечно, непонятные, но после исправления очепяток все должно заработать. Будьте внимательнее)

Comment: @АртемВагин, а что мне именно нужно находить?И как написать код чтоб мой обьект при клике перемещался вертикально ,а не горизонтально.Спасибо!

Comment: @АртемВагин, синус и косинус дают движение по окружности

Comment: Боюсь, не в этом примере. Чтобы получить движение элемента по окружности, нужно заморочиться гораздо больше - и лучше всего средствами css3 animation

Comment: @АртемВагин, не, вполне хватит, просто параметры в нужные места передать: https://jsfiddle.net/em2sar6v/

Answer (score 0):

```
var pi = Math.PI;
var rho = 0;
var rho2 = 0.5;

function peremeshenie() {
  document.getElementById('Ken').style.top = rho *
    Math.sin(pi) + 'px';
  rho += rho2;

}
setInterval(peremeshenie, 100);
```

Тогда объект будет перемещаться чисто по вертикали каждые 200 миллисекунд на некую величину (все-таки не понимаю, зачем вам тут тригонометрия).
В css:

```
#Ken {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```